# Uncaught Reference Error : firebase not defined at main.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, firebase, backend

Am trying to Connect Firebase to a Contact Form,
where requires the user to type and submit Fullname , Email and also Message.
But I face Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined at my main.js file
form my console.
I tried different solution but I couldn't be able to solve it.

Here is my script tag in my index.html

```
<script type="module">
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-app.js";
  </script>
  
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

here is my Main.js code

```
var config = {
  apiKey: "xxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxx"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);


var emailRef = firebase.database().ref('emails');


  // Listen for form submit
  document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

// Submit form
function submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault();

    //Get values
    var FullName = getInputval('FullName');
    var Email =getInputval('Email');

        // save message
        saveMessage(FullName,Email);
  
    // Show alert
    document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'block';
  
    // Hide alert after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'none';
    },3000);
  
    // Clear form
    document.getElementById('contactForm').reset();
  }
  

// Function to get  form values
function getInputval(id){
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

  
  // Save message to firebase
  function saveMessage(Fullname, Email,){
    var newEmailRef = emailRef.push();
    newEmailRef.set({
      Fullname: Fullname,
      Email:Email

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're initializing firebase here, it should be something like this:

```
const firebase = initializeApp(config);
```

For more info you can have a [look here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup)

Comment: I tried that one but still same error I get .

Comment: iinitializeApp is not defined

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? If you're still stuck, try importing and initializing the app in same page.

Comment: no, am now facing resolveWithNewModule error in my terminal  @Rajnish

Comment: Add another Question explaining your implementation, and link me to it. Let's see what can be done to resolve your issues

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69719247/main-js2-uncaught-reference-error-firebase-is-not-defined            
@Rajnish