# main.js:2 Uncaught Reference Error: firebase is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Am trying to link my html contact form with firebase, but am facing an error :

> Uncaught Reference Error: firebase is not defined

in my main.js file I defined my CDN in my html file well, but in main.js line
is where I face  this error in. I successful installed firebase in my project, but
still I face the same issue In the line below.

```
var emailRef = firebase.database().ref('emails');
```

Here in my main.js code

```
var emailRef = firebase.database().ref('emails');


  // Listen for form submit
  document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

// Submit form
function submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault();

    //Get values
    var FullName = getInputval('FullName');
    var Email =getInputval('Email');

        // save message
        saveMessage(FullName,Email);
  
    // Show alert
    document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'block';
  
    // Hide alert after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'none';
    },3000);
  
    // Clear form
    document.getElementById('contactForm').reset();
  }
  

// Function to get  form values
function getInputval(id){
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

  
  // Save message to firebase
  function saveMessage(Fullname, Email,){
    var newEmailRef = emailRef.push();
    newEmailRef.set({
      Fullname: Fullname,
      Email:Email

    });
  }
```

And in my index.html file here are my CDN format

```
<script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-app.js";
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-analytics.js";
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxx"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
</script>


<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second snippet is importing version 9 of Firebase in ES module format here:

```
<script type="module">
```

But then in the first snippet you try to use Firebase in its older syntax with  `firebase.database()`.

That won't work: you will have to either use the new import format and syntax, or use the older namespace syntax.

---

The equivalent to this v8 code:

```
var emailRef = firebase.database().ref('emails');
```

In [v9 modular syntax](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#get_a_database_reference) that'd be:

```
import { getDatabase, ref } from "firebase/database";

// Get a reference to the database service
const database = getDatabase(app);
var emailRef = ref(database, 'emails');
```

---

And this code in v8:

```
function saveMessage(Fullname, Email,){
  var newEmailRef = emailRef.push();
  newEmailRef.set({
    Fullname: Fullname,
    Email:Email

  });
}
```

Would look like this in [v9](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write):

```
import { getDatabase, ref, push, set } from "firebase/database";

function saveMessage(Fullname, Email,){
  var newEmailRef = push(emailRef);
  set(newEmailRef, {
    Fullname: Fullname,
    Email:Email
  });
}
```

---

When you're working with this combination of older and newer syntax, I recommend keeping the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) handy.